# Difference between UI and View in terminology and which is correct in what scenario

Tags: silverlight, model-view-controller, user-interface, mvvm, mvp

I am curious to see if there is a difference between the words "UI" and "View". I see UI can be classified as GUI, Voice User Interface, Commandline User Interface. But in our projects based on MVC/MVVM/MVP, we many a times interchange the term UI with View. I am little curious in knowing why 2 different words to represent the same thing ? Or what is the correct way of calling it ? (I know many people might say, its "View", but still why we use the jargon UI ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term user interface seems to be the correct term when you look at an application from a very abstract perspective. The user interface is simply the interface of an application the user interacts with.

The view, however, is more of a technical term.

As you already mentioned, a user interface sums up a very versatile set of *things* the user can use to interact with an application. The view is a specific type of UI, i.e. a graphical user interface made with a specific technology.

Comment: Thanks sir, that makes a lot of sense :) Thanks again for this explanation, cheers :)